# Removing files issue - Python

Tags: python-3.x

Hit a bit of a snag, receiving error 32 cannot access file because it is being used by another process. However, this error only occurs intermittently. Why would that be? It occasionally removes the file, other times it throws the error message.

if x and y:

```
for f in files:
    if f.endswith('.exe'):
        os.remove(f)
```

Comment: Antivirus maybe?

Comment: Yes! i added a delay to allow the process to finish and it works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Added delay to allow process to finish. Works!